# Google Api - Get users details

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, userinfo

I am using the Google Api PHP Client.

I want to get the details of the user who has logged in.

I am setting the following Scopes

```
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');

$request = new apiHttpRequest("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json");
  $userinfo = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($request);


  $response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($userinfo->getResponseBody()));
  print "<pre>" . print_r(json_decode($response, true), true) . "</pre>";
```

But i am not able to get the jSON from the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to Deleted the Question but didnt find any Answer that uses the PHP Client. so answering my own question

Just by replacing

```
$response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($userinfo->getResponseBody()));
```

by

```
$response = $userinfo->getResponseBody();
```